# Can't access element from within nested dict json (vue)

Tags: json, api, vue.js

I have the following json dict:

```
{
   "result_list":[
      {
         "device_id":"1",

         "latest_device_point":{
            "device_point_id":"6erDcYJtPkm58k81f07-0F",
            "dt_server":"2020-08-12T22:21:16.135338Z",
            "dt_tracker":"2020-08-12T22:21:13Z",
            "lat":33.9902063,
            "lng":-117.9827849,
            "altitude":137.34,
            "angle":192,
            "speed":0,
            },
      },
          "device_id":"2",

         "latest_device_point":{
            "device_point_id":"6erDcYJtPkm58k81f07-0F",
            "dt_server":"2020-08-12T22:21:16.135338Z",
            "dt_tracker":"2020-08-12T22:21:13Z",
            "lat":33.9902063,
            "lng":-117.9827849,
            "altitude":137.34,
            "angle":192,
            "speed":0,
            },
      },

    ...

}
```

And I would like to iterate over all devices in the list, and access their id and speed attributes in Vue:

```
        <div v-for="device in info" v-bind:key="device">
          <h7> ID# {{device.device_id}} </h7>
          <h7> Speed: {{device.latest_device_point.speed}} </h7> -->
        </div>
```

I have no issues getting the device_id, and can even get the entire dict at `device.latest_device_point`, but the code breaks when I try to access `{{device.latest_device_point.speed}}` with error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of null"`. What am I doing wrong?
This is my axios get call:

```
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get(path + this.key)
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data.result_list))
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit of a long shot but it could be the case that some elements in your list have `latest_device_point` where it is equal to `null`.

To stop if from breaking you could try to conditionally render this line:

```
<div v-for="device in info" v-bind:key="device.device_id">
   <h7> ID# {{device.device_id}} </h7>
   <h7 v-if="device.latest_device_point"> Speed: {{device.latest_device_point.speed}} </h7>
</div>
```

---

That will check if `device.latest_device_point` is null and only show `speed` property if it is not.

I would also recommend looking into your data to see if that is the case with `console.log`, for example.

Additionally, it would be ideal to use `device_id` as `key` instead of a full object.

---

Example of what could cause this error:

```js
let data = [
    {
       "device_id":"1",
       "latest_device_point": {
          "device_point_id":"6erDcYJtPkm58k81f07-0F",
          "dt_server":"2020-08-12T22:21:16.135338Z",
          "dt_tracker":"2020-08-12T22:21:13Z",
          "lat":33.9902063,
          "lng":-117.9827849,
          "altitude":137.34,
          "angle":192,
          "speed":0,
        },
    },
    {
       "device_id":"2",
       "latest_device_point": null
    }
]
console.log(data[0].latest_device_point.speed)
console.log(data[1].latest_device_point.speed)
```